# Virtual Alias File Using Regular Expression in Exim 4.89

Tags: virtualization, router, exim, regex, alias

I would like to thank you in advance for taking my question. I am deploying a mail server using Exim, version 4.89, and would like to use a virtual alias file using regular expression to forward incoming mail to an internal user.

My virtual alias file with regular expression include:

```
/^sample_.*@example.com$/ sample
/^sample@example.com$/ normaluser@outsidedomain.com
```

I haven't found examples when searching online. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is included in the basic configuration, see chapter 31 "Address rewriting" of the `exim` specification.